# maxArrayLength issue in silverlight

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I have been reading lots of articles on this issue for long, but i haven't got it worked.

Server Side web.config file
[image: Server Side web.config]

service.clientconfig
[image: service.clientconfig]

client side asp.net web.config
[image: client side asp.net web.config]

Still getting the following error

The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.

Any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed all the sizes to 2097152 instead of 2147483647 and it started working.
I have configured the web config for allowing 2MB. But it is throwing the same exception if i upload more than 1MB file.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this................

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="700" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: Thanks..It is working for me If I keep the Size 2097152 instead of 2147483647.